# I'm not sure how should interpret this sentence

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The sentence is a headline in NYtimes:

"In the U.S. cities that had some of the earliest Omicron surges, I.C.U. stays and deaths are following case curves upward."

My brain is having difficulty in connectiong the word "upward" that what is previously said,

whether it is like:

1. "I.C.U. stays and deaths are DRIVING ([case curves] upward)
2. "I.C.U. stays and deaths are matching case curves THAT IS upward

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret it like this:

The line on a graph showing Omicron cases in these cities curves in an upward direction. Adding ICU stays and deaths to the graph shows a similar curve, going in a similar upward direction.